# Trying to fix a do while loop in python.

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements, do-while

I mostly have experience programming in visual basic, and am trying to learn python.  I am trying to make a conditional loop in the form of a do until loop.  I am not sure how to do it in python and i could use some help.  I have a do until loop with an if statement within it. this is what i have.

```
number = 18
do while number = 1
if number%2==0 then
number = number/2
else number = (number*3)+1
loop 
print(number)
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: This isn't even close to being valid Python. You should really read through some sort of a tutorial.

Comment: This isn't even close to Python code. Python doesn't have `do while`, `then`, or `loop`. It requires colons after block-introducing statements like `if` and `else`. `number = 1` is an assignment, not a comparison (and it's a statement, not an expression). And so on.

Comment: I would suggest checking out a basic Python tutorial, as the code you've given does not demonstrate even a rudimentary understanding.

Comment: Python (when written well) looks very close to pseudo-code, it's true. But that still doesn't mean the interpreter is going to understand whatever you type in. Python has syntax rules, like any other language. Maybe in 500 years, we'll have a language with no syntax rules, an interpreter that just "guesses" what the user is trying to do and does it. But this is 2013, read some documentations :)

Comment: @ShashankGupta: We already had that: [Interlisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM).

Comment: @abarnert oh wow that's funny...I did not know they were already trying to do things like that. xD

Comment: @ShashankGupta: If you've ever met a Lisp fanatic, they'll tell you that Lisp did _everything_ decades before anyone else. That includes even the stupid things. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `do … while` loop in Python. I believe somewhere in the FAQ it explains why, and how to work around it.

But that doesn't matter because what you've written isn't a `do … while` loop, it's just a plain `while` loop. The whole point of a `do … while` in every language that has one is that you put the test condition after the loop body, instead of before, which guarantees that the loop will run at least once, and which allows you to avoid doing pre-loop setup that you'd have to duplicate inside the loop.

So, to translate your code to Python:

```
number = 18
while number == 1:
    if number%2==0:
        number = number/2
    else:
        number = (number*3)+1
print(number)
```

However, it's worth noting that since `number = 18` before the loop, it will never be `== 1` the first time through, so this is just going to skip the whole thing and print out `18`.

You may have wanted `while number != 1` or `while number > 1`, but you have to figure out what you actually want to write before anyone can write it.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful.  Thats for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'do/while' in Python. The closest is a loop that is guaranteed to loop once then get an exit test after 1 iteration.

```
while True:                          # kinda like 'do'
   # do something at least once
   if fail_condition():              # here is your 'while' test
       break                         # end the loop if 'fail_condition' is True
                                     # loop again if 'fail_condition' is not True
```

Roughly your code ([Collatz/Hailstone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Program_to_calculate_Hailstone_sequences)?) would look like this:

```
number, i = 18, 0
while number>1:
    i+=1
    if number%2==0:     
        number = number/2
    else: 
        number = (number*3)+1

print 'Reached {} after {} loops'.format(number,i)
# prints 'Reached 1 after 20 loops'
```

Answer (score -1):

is that above code even in python?  instead of do while, have it just be while. and after the if statement, dont have then. a quick reformatting would look something like this:

```
number = 18
while number == 18:
    if number%2==0:
        number = number/2
    else:
        number = (number*3)+1 
print(number)
```

Comment: This still isn't valid Python; `while number = 18:` will give you a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Those `+=`s should be just `=`s and the `print` function should be indented another level.

Comment: … or, if you think they should be `+=`, you've made a major change to the OP's algorithm without explaining it, or even mentioning that you've done so, which is unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: @Blender: I don't think the `print` should be indented. The OP put it after his `loop` statement in his unique language, which presumably maps to being outside the `while` block in Python. Plus, I'm pretty sure he just wants to print the number at the end, not all the steps along the way.

Comment: sorry i was in the middle of rewriting the whole thing, where the number was originally 0, then i went back, and forgot to take out the +=

Comment: @abarnert: I was just assuming the code was for the hailstone sequence, which probably terminates at 1 for every input.

Answer (score -2):

`do while` is not a usual construct in python. Simply use a `while` loop.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Your code could be modified as follows for instance.

```
number = 18
while number == 1:
    if ( number % 2 ) == 0:
        number = number / 2
    else:
        number = ( number * 3 ) + 1
print number
```

One of the biggest differences between these languages is that python is all about tab delimitation. You need not specify the start and end of a loop, the tabs do that for you. Additionally not the ':'s after conditional statements.

I would note however that the above code would not yield any valid answer. Perhaps you meant for the loop to run while number was not equal to 1?

Comment: This won't compile. And if it compiled it would never enter the loop.

Comment: Python is not a compiled language so that does not surprise me. Also, I am well aware it won't enter the loop. I addressed that fact in my answer.

Comment: So your source code is never compiled into python byte code? Not even JIT?

Comment: @DHandle: Wrong; Python _is_ a compiled language. It compiles to bytecode (which it then interprets) rather than machine code, but the same is true of Java, C#, etc.

Comment: Bro, just because it's an interpreted language doesn't mean it doesn't compile into something neater which it can interpret. Interpreted language != Not compiling.

Comment: (Well, technically, an implementation isn't _required_ to compile Python. But all of the major implementations do. And an implementation that didn't would still have to pretend to compile code, in order to implement, e.g., the [`codeop`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codeop.html) module required by the stdlib reference.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/24558/is-python-interpreted-or-compiled Semantics.

Comment: @DHandle: When Hyperboreus said "This won't compile", it's obvious what he meant: The Python compiler will give you a `SyntaxError` instead of generating bytecode. If you want to argue about whether the Python compiler is really a compiler or not, that's fine, but that wouldn't make his comment wrong in any way.

Comment: Meanwhile, why do you keep making trivial errors that do nothing but add new `IndentationError`s and/or `SyntaxError`s?

Comment: A smartass comment deserves a smartass reply.

Comment: @DHandle: So you respond to Shashank Gupta telling you to use 4 space indentations by adding an extra, illegal indent to your code, making it even farther away from running?

Comment: @abarnet Sorry I'm struggling with the formatting in codeblocks? It has nothing to do with the actual content of the answer. - And no, I responded to it by trying to correct the spacing in my answer.